Found errror 'Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion" is deprecated' in flutter 3.22.0

Warning: In index.html:66: Local variable for "serviceWorkerVersion"
is deprecated. Use "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}" template token
instead.
/C:/Users/NAFIS%20LIGARI/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/printing-5.11.0/lib/src/widget_wrapper.dart:173:11:
Error: No named parameter with the name 'size'.
size:
^^^^ /C:/Users/NAFIS%20LIGARI/flutter_sdk/flutter_windows_3.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:28:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.   const
ViewConfiguration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.

what is the solution for this bug, I'm using Flutter 3.22.0 latest version and this happened!
I searched on Google and it showed flutter_svg build on 2.19.0 is this create an issue?
